# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in \functions\node_modules\firebase\package.json

Tags: node.js, firebase

I am using firebase library in Nodejs code. When I try to deploy I am getting the below error:
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\jarvis_apis\functions\node_modules\firebase\package.json

I am using Node JS version 14.16.1